# Keep getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space error

Tags: maven, maven-2, jvm, out-of-memory, jvm-crash

I am required to start few servers locally. I keep getting the "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space" error every now and then. I tried to increase my JVM size by the following command.
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx128m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"

After running the above command, I see that the MAVEN_OPTS is correctly updated.
$ echo $MAVEN_OPTS
-Xmx128m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

However, after a few minutes from starting the servers I get an out of memory error.

$ echo $MAVEN_OPTS
-Xmx512m:wq

Can someone please tell me what causes the properties to change and what does the :wq come from?

Answer (score 1):

`wq` is the `vim` command for save and exit.
Looks like your jvm options got corrupted with that. Can you remove that and retry.

Increasing `-XX:MaxPermSize` is the correct thing to do here.